# How to remove :focus on Textinputfield when clicking somewhere else?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So when I click on the Textinputfield the "focus" is appearing and the container is lighting up.[image 2]
But when I click somewhere else or "ok" the "focus" doesn't disappear.[image 3]
Has anybody an idea how to fix that?

[1.image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rQQm.png)

[2.image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftbvh.png)

[3.image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnzdf.png)

Comment: Can you please share your layout code in the question?

Comment: Are you sure you want to mess around with that? What you're describing is standard behaviour, and changing the focus can be confusing for people using hardware keyboards and accessibility services. You can force it to act differently if you want (that's your call) but it's not something that needs fixing - it's meant to be like that

Answer (score 0):

You can override  `dispatchTouchEvent`  for that. You can check if current focus is on your `TextInputEditText`  if so you can `clearfocus` & close the keyboard if needed.

Let's understand this with example:

Following is layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in Activity I will override the method as suggested, Main thing to focus on is `dispatchTouchEvent` :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val etName = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.etName)
    }

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            val v = currentFocus
            if (v is TextInputEditText) {
                val outRect = Rect()
                v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
                if (!outRect.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) {
                    v.clearFocus()
                    val imm = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0)
                }
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }

}
```

When `ACTION_DOWN` (touch) happens you get to decide based on `currentfocus` whether  you should clear focus or not. You can use do this based on `view.id` as well.